# Is it safe to use Realm freeze() method to get objects in the entire Swift project?

Tags: swift, realm

Is it safe (memory, disk space consuming, performance) to use Realm freeze() method to get objects for read in the entire Swift project?
I don't want to use own POJO structures, but use objects that freeze() method returns.

Comment: Not sure the question is clear. You would typically use freeze() and thaw() when you need to pass realm between threads. But in general that should not be a common thing. What's the use case? Do you have some code? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for a comment. There is no particular code. I want to use freeze() for reading objects from Realm and pass them to some different thread. Seems to me I could completely rely on those freeze objects in order not to get incorect thread exception.

Comment: I've never heard of thaw() though. Is a "thawed" object tied to a thread where if was "thawed"?

Comment: @Jay please tell me why you've written "But in general that should not be a common thing"? What is the common thing that I should use to work with Realm objects if I need them on the different thread?

Comment: Without some code, he question doesn't really have context. In other words - *get objects for read in the entire Swift project* - what does that mean? Entire project? Are you going to load 1,000,000 realm objects and keep them in a singleton? What's the purpose of keeping objects in the project - what if you don't need them or all of them in a view? We really need to understand the use case.

Comment: To modify a frozen object, use the .thaw() function as shown in the documentation [Modify a Frozen Object with thaw](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/advanced-guides/threading/#modify-a-frozen-object)

Comment: Threading - if you haven't done so, please read [Threading](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/advanced-guides/threading/#threading---ios-sdk). Realm is fast and often times objects can be used within the (main) thread without affecting the UI. However, for example, writing 1,000,000 on the main thread can 'lock' the UI. In those cases the write should be done on a background thread to keep the UI performant. However, there would only be 'some' cases were all of those objects *then* need to then be used on the main thread - hence my comment *should not be a common thing*.

Comment: Thank you Jay. I really can't show any code and I totally agree with you about that. I'd like to know some common practices of using Realm in iOS projects.

Comment: I've finally found the topic of my concern: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6980 and seems to me it is okay to get objects with freeze(), use them on any thread and, if I want to modify them, use thaw(). I hope since then Realm works only better)

Comment: You can do that but keep in mind when objects are frozen, they do not update live and only exist in the state they were in. In a real world case; suppose you have a calendar with events, and when the details of an event change, the calendar should be updated. If the events are frozen, that functionality will be missing - no live updates.

Comment: Yes, I do understand this. Thank you!

Comment: @Jay One more question: I know how to get thread-safe object (realm.object(id: id).freeze()) But is there any difference if I call it like this: realm.freeze().object(id: id)
?

Comment: Those are going to be quite different. One freezes the object, and the other freezes the entire Realm.

Comment: Is the second one, which freezes the entire realm, has a bigger impact on memory?

Comment: I would guess so as the objects in the realm would no longer be lazily loaded to allow them to be passed between threads. However, that is a *guess* and not a fact. You should be able to test the memory footprint with XCode.